# I failing in storing all the values against a class using selenium web driver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is the basic HTML

ul id="yui_3_7_0_4_1389361094754_395" class="dropdown-menu"

```
<li class="action" value="4001"></li>
<li class="action" value="4003"></li>
<li class="action" value="4004"></li>
<li class="action" value="4005"></li>
<li class="action" value="4006"></li>
<li class="action" value="4007"></li>
<li class="action" value="4008"></li>
<li id="yui_3_7_0_4_1389361094754_394" class="action" value="4009"></li>
<li class="action" value="65512"></li>
<li class="action" value="65514"></li>
<li class="action" value="67959"></li>
<li class="action" value="67960"></li>
<li class="action" value="102091"></li>
```

and this is my code

```
    select_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("action") 
    options = [x for x in select_box.get_attribute("value")] 
    for element in options:
        print element.get_attribute("value")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [find_elements_by_class_name()](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_class_name) instead:

```
select_boxes = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("action")
for select_box in select_boxes:
    print select_box.get_attribute("value")
```